# Lagrangian Dual

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems

As part of an applied math class for biologists I am in which is partly concerned with optimization and  duality we have been referred to a text to help us understand the concepts better.  I do not understand the solution to one of the questions.  It is question 5.13 from the pdf: https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364a/hw5sol.pdf.
I absolutely cannot figure out how they eliminated the dual multiplier $v_i$ for this portion of the solution.  Also I do not understand what the notation $min\{0,4(c_i + a_{i}^T \mu\}$ means.  Forgive me for I am not a math student.  I am amazed I can even understand what a relaxation is and how it is used in duality.  I may have used the wrong tags for that reason as well.

I am specifically stuck here:
[image]

The step before " in order to simplify this dual..." I believe to be...

$$ \max -\frac{1}{4\mu}\Sigma_{i=1}^n (c_i + a_{i}^T \mu - v_i)^2/ v_i $$
$$s.t. \text{  } v_i \geqq 0, \mu_i \geqq 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dual problem is
$$\max -b^\top \mu - \frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(c_i+a_i^\top\mu-\nu_i)^2}{\nu_i} \quad \mbox{s.t.} \quad \mu \geq 0, \nu \geq 0.
$$
Obviously the term $b^\top \mu$ does not depend on $\nu$.
Hence, to further investigate the role of $\nu$ it is suffcient to consider the latter part of the objctive function, which is
$$\max - \frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(c_i+a_i^\top\mu-\nu_i)^2}{\nu_i} \quad \mbox{s.t.} \quad \mu \geq 0, \nu \geq 0.$$
Now, the idea is to focus on the single summands and to maximize those summands. The background is that if we maximize all summands, then we also maximize the whole sum. Thus, we consider (for fixed $\mu$) the summand for an arbitrary $i = 1,\ldots,n$ which leads to the mentioned problem
$$ \sup -\frac{(c_i+a_i^\top\mu-\nu_i)^2}{\nu_i} \quad \mbox{s.t.} \quad \nu_i \geq 0.$$
We find out, that the term that we want to maximize (find the supremum of) has negative sign. Also both parts of the fraction are not negative. Hence, the supremum is definitely bounded (above) by $0$.
As written in the solution we can now distinguish between two cases: If $c_i+a_i^\top\mu \geq 0$ then we can always find $\nu_i \geq 0$ such that $c_i+a_i^\top\mu - \nu_i = 0$ and hence the supremum is $0$.

If $c_i+a_i^\top\mu < 0$ then one can find out analytically (using first + second derivative) that the supremum is obtained for $\nu_i = -c_i+a_i^\top\mu$. More precisely, define
$$\begin{align}
g(\nu_i) := &-\frac{(c_i+a_i^\top\mu-\nu_i)^2}{\nu_i}\\
= &-\frac{(c_i+a_i^\top\mu)^2+\nu_i^2-2(c_i+a_i^\top\mu)\nu_i}{\nu_i}\\
= &-\frac{(c_i+a_i^\top\mu)^2}{\nu_i}-\nu_i+2(c_i+a_i^\top\mu).
\end{align}$$
Then we have
$$ \begin{align}
g^\prime(\nu_i) &= \frac{(c_i+a_i^\top\mu)^2}{\nu_i^2}-1\\
g^{\prime\prime}(\nu_i) &= -\frac{2(c_i+a_i^\top\mu)^2}{\nu_i^3}
\end{align}$$
This is all we need to find the global maximum:
$$g^\prime(\nu_i) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \nu_i^2 = (c_i+a_i^\top\mu)^2 \Rightarrow \nu_i = -(c_i+a_i^\top\mu).$$
The sign is known since we have $\nu_i \geq 0$ and $c_i+a_i^\top\mu < 0$.
Also, this choice of $\nu_i$ implies $\nu_i > 0$ and thus, $g^{\prime\prime}(\nu_i) < 0$. Hence, we have $$-\frac{(c_i+a_i^\top\mu-\nu_i)^2}{\nu_i} = -\frac{(c_i+a_i^\top\mu-(-c_i+a_i^\top\mu))^2}{-c_i+a_i^\top\mu} = 4(c_i+a_i^\top\mu) \leq 0$$
in this case.
For this reason, we can write that the the supremum equals the minimum of those two terms from the case destinction above, i.e.,
$$ \sup_{\nu_i \geq 0} -\frac{(c_i+a_i^\top\mu-\nu_i)^2}{\nu_i} = \min \{0,4(c_i+a_i^\top\mu)\}.$$
(The minimum of those two terms is $0$ if $c_i+a_i^\top\mu \geq 0$ and $c_i+a_i^\top\mu$ if $c_i+a_i^\top\mu < 0$ - exactly what we found out above.)

As $\nu$ is no longer part of that term (of the minimum above), it can be eliminated from the dual problem when inserting the minimum for the summands.
This finally leads to the dual problem
$$\max -b^\top \mu + \sum_{i=1}^n \min \{0,c_i+a_i^\top\mu\} \quad \mbox{s.t.} \quad \mu \geq 0.$$

Comment: "If ci+a⊤iμ≤0 then one can find out analytically (using first + second derivative) that the supremum is obtained for ν_i=c_i+a⊤iμ and hence we have..." I don't see how that value for vi is obtained, To me its looks like vi should be equal to  ci+aTiμ    I could see how the first derivative could be involved but not the second.  Do you end up needing a 3x3 Jacobian matrix for all the partials of $v_i=c_i+a_i^T\mu$?

Comment: @AngusCampbell I included an explanation in my answer

Comment: Sorry I was having trouble solving for the derivative.  I ended up using a derivative calculator in the end and as per your instructions going to the second derivative.  Thank you for explaining this.  I worked my way through the problem using your directions and it was  a great help to me!